# Modify text in a range of columns if the data = a key word

Tags: unix, awk

Apologies, I'm very new to unix. I've searched for the answer, but to be honest would probably not recognise it at this stage of my unix journey.

I have a tab-delimited file (large - 800 columns by 5000 rows).

I would like to change a word to a number every time that word is found, but only within a range of columns. If the word is matched in other columns it remains unmodified.

i.e. change x to 9 but only in columns 2,3, and 4.
Input file:

`1  2   x   4   5   6
1   x   3   4   5   6
1   2   x   4   x   6
1   x   3   x   x   6`

Expected output file

`1  2   9   4   5   6
1   9   3   4   5   6
1   2   9   4   x   6
1   9   3   9   x   6`

Within the real input file, I need to modify a large number of columns within a continuous range (i.e. coloumns 7-487)

Any help welcome.
Cheers
GTed

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward way to do that,

```
awk '$2=="x"{$2=9}$3=="x"{$3=9}$4=="x"{$4=9}1' file
```

Brief explanation,

- Change `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` to 9 if it's "x"
- The append `1` is used to print the output

As the further request of OP,
modify the answer for the range of fields,

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=4;i++)$i=($i=="x")?9:$i}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I need to expand this to 480 columns (out of my total 800). Can I specify a range rather than 480 separate entries?

Comment: @GTed Please see my edit for your request, you can modify start and end field 
 (i.e. 2 & 4 in the answer) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

The following makes the replacement on columns 2, 3, and 4 as requested:

```
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= 4; i++)
         if ($i == "x") $i = 9
       print}' InputFile.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help - that has worked well on the small test file :)

Answer (score 0):

To make this question's answer Generic following may help you on same. Where I am considering few things.

i- Let's say you want to replace strings `x`,`y`,`z` on places `2`,`3`,`4` on each line with `9`,`11`,`12`.

ii- I am considering that number of string to be replaced with new strings will be always same.

iii- Considering following is Input_file to test code is behaving well or not here too.

Let's say following is a test Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
1  2   x   4   5   6
1   x   3   4   5   6
1   2   x   4   x   6
1   x   3   x   x   6
1   z   6   y   6   y
```

Following is the code for same.

```
awk -v strings="x,y,z"  -v places="2,3,4" -v replaces="9,11,12" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(strings, a,",");
  num1=split(places, b,",");
  num2=split(replaces, c,",")}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     for(j=1;j<=num1;j++){
       if($i==a[j]){
        $i=c[j]}}}
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.(you could add `OFS="\t"` too in above code to get output in TAB delimited form)

```
1 2 9 4 5 6
1 9 3 4 5 6
1 2 9 4 9 6
1 9 3 9 9 6
1 12 6 11 6 11
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

specify the columns for replacement in a space delimited list in `cols` variable.

```
$ awk -v cols='2 3 4' 'BEGIN{split(cols,c)} 
                            {for(i in c) sub("x",9,$c[i])}1' file

1 2 9 4 5 6
1 9 3 4 5 6
1 2 9 4 x 6
1 9 3 9 x 6
```

**UPDATE**
To give a range of columns instead, you can use below

```
$ awk -v cols='2-4' 'BEGIN{split(cols,c,"-")} 
                          {for(i=c[1];i<=c[2];i++) sub("x",9,$i)}1' file
```

**NB** To get tab delimited output set `-v OFS='\t'`